# create user with only permissions to execute C Programs

Tags: root, chroot, node.js

I am trying to build online code editor. My scenario : Through the web server a request is received for a 'C' program -the root user creates the file, compiles the file and acks success to the user.

We are using `nodejs` in our backend . Now is the time to run the program - `nodejs` provides us an option to spawn this user code with a uid (a different user other than root).

How do I go about creating a user which does not have any powers like ls, px - but just simply runs the executable compiled in the above steps.

one of the solutions that I tried : change permission of `/usr/bin`, `/bin`, `/usr/sbin/`, `/sbin`, `/usr/local/bin` , `/usr/local/sbin` to 700 so only root user can 
run all of these command and this user just runs simple "C" programs. But still this user has a option to view the `/etc` directories - so basically I need a user 
where all directories are with 700. Is this a good idea ?

Other option is to apparmor. Have not tried this one yet.

Third option that was suggested by a friend is chroot but people say that its not for security measures.

Can some one guide me how do I go about this problem.

Comment: If your looking for a user to only execute certain C programs (not including the /bin and /sbin scripts) why don't you create a group for all the executable C programs and change the permissions so that the programs are accessible to the user:group (again not including the /bin and /sbin files)

Comment: Yeah I tried a similar solution by changing all perms to 700 . Would make sense to create a grp with limited perms and then run programs being user of that group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chroot is the more traditional way of doing this, and you can make it work, but since you're doing this via a web interface, it gets a little complicated: you must prevent race conditions (multiple users from using the same chroot environment), you must dynamically build a directory structure for each request, and probably a few other things I can't think of off the top of my head.

If you're using Linux, you want to look at containers (`lxc`) or the Docker project  https://docs.docker.com. The Docker platform in particular will very nicely and easily let you do what you want here: create short-lived, lightweight virtual systems that can be used to run entirely jailed processes with no effect on external (ie, your web server's) resources. You can download a basic docker image of the specific OS environment you want the program to run off (say, Fedora 12), tell docker to run that environment while importing your user's program source into that environment, and then tell docker to run the compiler and resulting file within that environment. Then you tell docker to destroy the ephemeral environment. Nothing stays behind, (almost) no security risk.

Comment: Yeah I even came across containers as solution . What are your thoughts on LXGA's reply.

Comment: @jitenshah I see that LXGA edited your post, but I don't see a reply/ comment/answer from him.

Comment: sorry I meant ryekayo. mybad.